# Javascript - check if two sets of checkboxes have been left unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I've got 2 sets of checkboxes; we'll call them a and b. I've written a script which disables the a's checkboxes if any of the checkboxes in b have been selected and vice versa.

Currently, I'm trying to write a script which will check if both a and b have been left unchecked. If they have been left unchecked, throw an alert telling the user and also cancel the submit function as I have assigned the function as an onclick to the submit button. How can I do this?

I've added the html and Javascript below:

HTML:

```
  <center>
    <div class="col-2">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the day(s) of the month the task should be set at</h4>
            </li>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DofMID)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DofMNo)
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DofMInfo.Count; i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                    <div class="checkbox-inline" id="checkboxDofM">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DofMInfo[i].DofMID)
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DofMInfo[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkboxDofM" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DofMInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.DofMInfo[i].DofMNo)
                    </div>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</center>

<center>
    <div class="col-3">
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item-heading list-group-item active">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-text">Select the day(s) the task should be set at</h4>
            </li>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.dayID)
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.dayName)
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DayInfo.Count; i++)
            {
                <li class="list-group-item" style="display:inline-block">
                    <div class="checkbox-inline" id="checkboxDay">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].dayID)
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].IsChecked, new { @class = "checkboxDay" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.DayInfo[i].IsChecked, Model.DayInfo[i].dayName)
                    </div>
                </li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
    </center>
<input type="submit" value="Submit Data" id="btnSubmit" onclick='return EmptyFields();' />
```

Javascript:

```
//blocks one set of checkboxes if the other is selected
    function DaysBlocker() {
        checkboxDayElement.forEach(function (item) {
            item.disabled = false;
        });

        checkboxDofMElement.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item.checked) {

                checkboxDayElement.forEach(function (item2) {
                    item2.disabled = true;
                });
            }
        });
    }
    function DofmBlocker() {
        checkboxDofMElement.forEach(function (a) {
            a.disabled = false;
        });

        checkboxDayElement.forEach(function (a) {
            if (a.checked) {
                checkboxDofMElement.forEach(function (b) {
                    b.disabled = true;
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Javascript related to the question and what I've done so far:

```
 function EmptyFields() {

    var checkedField = true;

    checkboxDofMElement.forEach(function (a) {
        if (a.checked = false) {
            checkedField = false;

            checkboxDayElement.forEach(function (b) {
                if (b.checked = false) {
                    checkedField = false;
                }
            });

        }
    });

    alert("You have to select either a day(s) of the month or a day(s) of the week");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You want to use triple equal signs when checking for equality in your conditional statements.

Comment: @chevybow I've removed the checkField variable and I've used the triple === signs in the conditional statement. Even if one of the fields are checked or both have been left unchecked, I still receive an error message.

Comment: Would be helpful if you include the error message.

Comment: @chevybow By error message, I meant alert. I'm sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out how to solve the problem like this:

```
            function EmptyFields() {

            var checkedField = false;

            checkboxDayElement.forEach(function (a) {
                if (a.checked) {
                    checkedField = true;
                }
            });

            checkboxDofMElement.forEach(function (b) {
                if (b.checked) {
                    checkedField = true;
                }
            });

            if (!checkedField) {
                alert("You have to select either a day(s) of month or a day(s) of week");
            } else {
                alert("Task has been set");
            }


            return checkedField;

        }
```

It was a matter of restructuring the code I initially had and adding an if statament at the bottom to express the logic properly with the boolean. I thank the contributors for their help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `checkedField` variable around alerting. Also, `=` is assignment, you need to use `==` or `===` for comparison. Or, in the case of boolean values, just use the variable itself.

And you have the logic backwards -- `checkedField` should be false until you determine that both boxes are checked.

But you can use the `.some()` function to check if at least one box is checked in each group.

```
function EmptyFields() {

    var checkedField = checkboxDofMElement.some(a => a.checked) || checkboxDayElement.some(a => a.checked);

    if (!checkedField) {
        alert("You have to select either a day(s) of the month or a day(s) of the week");
    }
    return checkedField;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, however the .some method would not work.